# How can I have multiple *Help* buffers with different content?

Tags: buffers, help

Using `C-h f` and `C-h v` shows usefull help. Sometimes I want to compare information.  So it would be useful to have more than one `*Help*` buffer, with different content, visible at the same time.

But always when using the shortcuts the content of the `*Help*` buffer gets overwritten.

How to have more than one help (`*Help*`) buffer open at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `rename-uniquely`. Go to the help buffer, call `rename-uniquely`. It renames the buffer to something like `*Help*<2>`. Now If you open another help buffer, it doesn't affect `*Help*<2>`.

> (rename-uniquely)
>
> Rename current buffer to a similar name not already taken.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true with Emacs 28. Neither `rename-uniquely` nor `clone-buffer` retain their state after a new help topic is viewed.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use command/function **`clone-buffer`**.

`M-x clone-buffer` in buffer `*Help*` opens a new buffer `*Help*<2>` (or `*Help*<3>` if there is already a buffer `*Help*<2>`, etc.).

Same thing, if you use `M-x clone-buffer` in buffer `*Help*<2>`: you get `*Help*<3>` (or `*Help*<4>` if there is already a buffer `*Help*<3>`, etc.).

You can use `clone-buffer` pretty much anywhere. It's very useful in Info, for instance.

---

(This being said, personally I bind a key (`C-M-S-<f1>`) to `rename-buffer`, and I use that quite often.  The default is the current buffer name, which I often want to edit only slightly for the new name.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the above answers, I wrote a small function which clones a help buffer on keypress.
Stuff both code snippets in you `init.el` to have it always available.

```
(defun jue-clone-buffer ()
        "jue clone current buffer. Useful to have multiple help buffers."
        (interactive)
        (clone-buffer (concat (buffer-name) "-"                 ; create name from old name and
                              (save-excursion                   ; use first word in buffer for new name
                                  (goto-char 0)
                                  (thing-at-point 'word t)))
                      t)))                                      ; show cloned buffer now
```

Bind the new function to key 'c' in help-mode:

```
(define-key help-mode-map (kbd "c") 'jue-clone-buffer)
```

*Note*:
You could use this function for other buffers also, not only `*Help*` buffers.
If you clone a buffer a second time, there is `<N>` appended to the name, where `N` is a number.